# Bootstrap with MVC4 does not create bootstrap.css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

This is not the Bootstrap-MVC4 nuget package. That failed to install, with jQuery version issues (in Bootstrap land, 1.8.2 is either less than 1.4.4 or greater than 2.0; it didn't say which). I found another one on nuget but it introduced unresolvable .NET assembly dependencies in BundleConfig.cs and I reverted.

I followed these directions here: https://www.macaw.nl/weblog/2013/5/setting-up-a-solution-with-mvc4-and-twitter-bootstrap

```
PM> Install-Package Twitter.Bootstrap.Less
PM> Install-Package html5shiv
```

So far so good, but bootstrap.css does not exist. His solution tree has it; mine does not

[image: Missing bootstrap.css in solution tree]:

Are the above packages able to create bootstrap.css? If so, how can they be made to do that? If not, what do I need to change?

Comment: In the article you referenced the author also indicated that he installed the Web Essentials add-in for Visual Studio. Have you done that?  You need Web Essentials or similar to compile `.less` files to `.css`

Comment: If you've already got Web Essentials installed, try make a meaningless edit of the `bootstrap.less` file (i.e. edit, add a space, delete the space, then save) to dirty the file -- this should trigger a compile.